# Order objects according to their place in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-scripting

I made this collage with CercleFill Script in Adobe Illustrator, it's a great result but the cercles are in random order, I found an other Adobe Illustrator script that can order layers alphabetly, but isn't the case I want.

I look for any script or plug-in that can make this cercles in order according to their place if it possible.

I hope my question is clear

[image]

Comment: So you would like the layers to be ordered according to the position of each object in your design, is that it?

Comment: Yes, if is it possible